# Async functions in Django views

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-views

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
def new_query(request,company_uuid,address_uuid,contact_uuid):
    mcompany = get_object_or_404(Company, uuid=company_uuid)
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = forms.CompanyQueryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            mquery = form.save(commit = False)
            mcompany = get_object_or_404(Company, uuid = company_uuid)
            mquery.company = mcompany
            mquery.version_number = 1
            mquery.parameters = {
                                    'company':company_uuid,
                                    'address':address_uuid,
                                    'contact':contact_uuid
                                    }
            mquery.save()
            preserialise(mquery.pk, company_uuid)
            recent_update = RecentUpdate(company_query=mquery, update_type="1")
            recent_update.save()
            url = reverse('view_directory',kwargs={'company_uuid':company_uuid,
                                                                'address_uuid':address_uuid,
                                                                'contact_uuid':contact_uuid})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = forms.CompanyQueryForm()
    return share.output_page(request,'joinerysoft/new_query.html',{'title':unicode(u'New Company Query'),
                                                                   'form': form,
                                                                   'company':mcompany,
                                                                   'address_uuid':address_uuid,
                                                                   'contact_uuid':contact_uuid})
```

where `preserialise(mquery.pk, company_uuid)` runs in the background without waiting to return? as pre-serialisation takes a long time to complete (over 5 minutes) and I'd like it to be a fire and forget from the perspective of the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always fire off a thread:

```
import threading

class PreserializeThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, mquery_pk, company_uuid, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mquery_pk = mquery_pk
        self.company_uuid = company_uuid
        super(PreserializeThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        preserialize(self.mquery_pk, self.company_uuid)
```

Then, replace `preserialize` in your code sample with:

```
PreserializeThread(mquery.pk, company_uuid).start()
```

See also: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

Comment: Would you recommend this or a more robust task queuing app like Celery? I guess each one has their own pros and cons but I'm not sure if stick to the simple python threads or go with celery.

Comment: I think this one simple task is overkill for Celery. If you were doing lots of this stuff and more complicated tasks that require monitoring, then, yes, Celery is where you should turn.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, no.

Your function will take until serialization is finished before continuing execution.

Have a look at [django-celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/index.html) for a task queuing solution.

As of 2020, [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) now supports Django out of the box.

Comment: If it makes it easier, there is no data to return from the function, and so it's more like an event..

Comment: It doesn't work that way, your function must complete before continuing

Comment: Does Async support change anything? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/